# How do i query this data from mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i need help to get this data from my tables.

Every user will have a quantity for each ordnance type, and each ordnance type has other stuff i need to get price/atk/def/title

currently i use the sql command

```
SELECT ordnance_1, ordnance_2, ordnance_3, ordnance_4, ordnance_5
FROM ordnance
WHERE token = 0aced48360c0f30e;
```

these are the quantities from the ordnance table, how can i also get the descriptions for the ordnance?

ordnance_1 quantity = row 1 of ordnanceDetails table

ordnance_2 quantity = row 2 of ordnanceDetails table
ect

so if i searched with token 0aced48360c0f30e the data i would get back would be

```
12, Rocket Bomb, 25000, 1250000, 50000,
10, Proximity EMP, 50000, 100000, 200000,
25, cluster Bomb, 50000, 215000, 10000 ect.
```

Is it possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you must have a column for relationship in ordnanceDetails table , i think you forget that to mention it . and another question is the relationship between this tables are One-to-One ?

Comment: im not sure what column i would add for relationship in ordnanceDetails, this is where i am confused maybe. I think it would have to be a one-to-one relationship, each ordnance quantity in ordnance can only have one ordnanceDetail.

Comment: I would have only one table containing  1 ordnance item per row.

Comment: i was thinking this an existing database and you want to query on it , if you can change the database design you must have put these data on one table and forget any problem in this case !!

Comment: i edited to add data, and hopefully clarify my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the ordnance table to have one ordnance item per row, like P.Salmon said. Mohammad Mirzaeyan gave me info to look into one-to-many relationships. Due To your comments I was able to come to this solution that works for me.

[image]

[image]

SQL Query

```
SELECT O.token, O.ordnance_quantity, I.title, I.price, I.attack_boost, I.defense_boost 
FROM ordnance O 
JOIN ordnance_details I ON O.ordnance_type = I.ordnance_details_id 
WHERE token = '0aced48360c0f30e'
```

Result

[image]